# Trying to set SSLCipherSuite and SSLHonorCipherOrder via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

so i am trying to set some SSL settings via .htaccess but i get internal server error.

Error log shows following error:
**/home/myuser/xxxx.com/.htaccess: SSLProtocol not allowed here**

I want to prefer stronger ciphers before weaker.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "deny"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "img-src *"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"



AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
Require valid-user

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

AuthUserFile "/home/myuser/.htpasswds/xxxxxx.com/passwd"
```

Webserver is on shared webhosting with cpanel and letsencrypt.

Can this be done via .htaccess at all?

Comment: If you can, and especially for security related settings, it is far better to use Apache main configuration files instead of relying on `.htaccess` files. If you do that, you gain performance, simplicity and security. But other than that, your question is more for [sf] than here as it is not related to programming, and Steffen gave the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be done via .htaccess at all?

From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol):

> **SSLProtocol** Directive 
> ... 
> Context:    server config, virtual host
> ...
>   **SSLCipherSuite** Directive
> ...
> Context:   server config, virtual host, directory, **.htaccess**

Thus, `SSLProtocol` will not work in `.htaccess` while `SSLCipherSuite` should.